# Horizontal stacked bar in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, exploratory-data-analysis

So I'm working with the world happiness report 2017. At the end, I want to create an horizontal stacked bar showing how each metric contributes to the total happiness of each country.
I tried doing it in a thousand different ways, but every time I get a different error. I even copied a code and tweaked the necessary things, but even that shows an error.
Can someone help me out?

I'll attach the csv file at the end.

This is the original code that I tried

```
cols = report_final.columns
left_list = []
for i in cols:
    plt.barh(report_final["Country"], report_final[i], left = left_list)
    left_list.append(i)
```

This showed the error

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

This is the code that I copied from internet

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10, 30))

cols = report_final.columns
left = len(report_final) * [0]
for name in cols:
    plt.barh(report_final["Country"], report_final[name], left = left)
    left = left + report_final[name]
```

This gives the error

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

I also tried doing it without the loop, one by one. It still gives the error

```
TypeError: Cannot broadcast np.ndarray with operand of type <class 'list'>
```

This is a code that gave an output, but it's incorrect

```
cols = report_final.columns
left_list = []
plt.figure(figsize= (10,45))
for i in range(len(report_final)):
    left_list = []
    for j in cols:
        plt.barh(report_final.at[i,"Country"], report_final.at[i,j], left = left_list)
        left_list.append(j)
```

[image: Incorrect graph]

Any help will be appreciated

CSV file

```
,Country,Economy  GDP per Capita ,Family,Health  Life Expectancy ,Freedom,Generosity,Trust  Government Corruption ,Dystopia Residual
0,Norway,1.61646318435669,1.53352355957031,0.796666502952576,0.635422587394714,0.36201223731041,0.315963834524155,2.27702665328979
1,Denmark,1.48238301277161,1.55112159252167,0.792565524578094,0.626006722450256,0.355280488729477,0.40077006816864,2.31370735168457
2,Iceland,1.480633020401,1.6105740070343,0.833552122116089,0.627162635326385,0.475540220737457,0.153526559472084,2.32271528244019
3,Switzerland,1.56497955322266,1.51691174507141,0.858131289482117,0.620070576667786,0.290549278259277,0.367007285356522,2.2767162322998
4,Finland,1.44357192516327,1.5402467250824,0.80915766954422,0.617950856685638,0.24548277258873,0.38261154294014,2.4301815032959
5,Netherlands,1.50394463539124,1.42893922328949,0.810696125030518,0.585384488105774,0.470489829778671,0.282661825418472,2.29480409622192
6,Canada,1.47920441627502,1.48134899139404,0.83455765247345,0.611100912094116,0.435539722442627,0.287371516227722,2.18726444244385
7,New Zealand,1.40570604801178,1.54819512367249,0.816759705543518,0.614062130451202,0.500005125999451,0.382816702127457,2.0464563369751
8,Sweden,1.49438726902008,1.47816216945648,0.830875158309937,0.612924098968506,0.385399252176285,0.384398728609085,2.09753799438477
9,Australia,1.484414935112,1.51004195213318,0.84388679265976,0.601607382297516,0.477699249982834,0.301183730363846,2.06521081924438
10,Israel,1.37538242340088,1.37628996372223,0.83840399980545,0.405988603830338,0.330082654953003,0.0852421000599861,2.80175733566284
11,Costa Rica,1.10970628261566,1.41640365123749,0.759509265422821,0.580131649971008,0.214613229036331,0.100106589496136,2.89863920211792
12,Austria,1.48709726333618,1.4599449634552,0.815328419208527,0.567766189575195,0.316472321748734,0.221060365438461,2.1385064125061
13,United States,1.54625928401947,1.41992056369781,0.77428662776947,0.505740523338318,0.392578780651093,0.135638788342476,2.2181134223938
14,Ireland,1.53570663928986,1.55823111534119,0.80978262424469,0.573110342025757,0.42785832285881,0.29838815331459,1.77386903762817
15,Germany,1.48792338371277,1.47252035140991,0.798950731754303,0.562511384487152,0.336269170045853,0.276731938123703,2.01576995849609
16,Belgium,1.46378076076508,1.46231269836426,0.818091869354248,0.539770722389221,0.231503337621689,0.251343131065369,2.12421035766602
17,Luxembourg,1.74194359779358,1.45758366584778,0.845089495182037,0.59662789106369,0.283180981874466,0.31883442401886,1.61951208114624
18,United Kingdom,1.44163393974304,1.49646008014679,0.805335938930511,0.508190035820007,0.492774158716202,0.265428066253662,1.70414352416992
19,Chile,1.25278460979462,1.28402495384216,0.819479703903198,0.376895278692245,0.326662421226501,0.0822879821062088,2.50958585739136
20,United Arab Emirates,1.62634336948395,1.26641023159027,0.726798236370087,0.60834527015686,0.3609419465065,0.324489563703537,1.734703540802
21,Brazil,1.10735321044922,1.43130600452423,0.616552352905273,0.437453746795654,0.16234989464283,0.111092761158943,2.76926708221436
22,Czech Republic,1.35268235206604,1.43388521671295,0.754444003105164,0.490946173667908,0.0881067588925362,0.0368729270994663,2.45186185836792
23,Argentina,1.18529546260834,1.44045114517212,0.695137083530426,0.494519203901291,0.109457060694695,0.059739887714386,2.61400532722473
24,Mexico,1.15318381786346,1.210862159729,0.709978997707367,0.412730008363724,0.120990432798862,0.132774114608765,2.83715486526489
25,Singapore,1.69227766990662,1.35381436347961,0.949492394924164,0.549840569496155,0.345965981483459,0.46430778503418,1.21636199951172
26,Malta,1.34327983856201,1.48841166496277,0.821944236755371,0.588767051696777,0.574730575084686,0.153066068887711,1.55686283111572
27,Uruguay,1.21755969524384,1.41222786903381,0.719216823577881,0.57939225435257,0.175096929073334,0.178061872720718,2.17240953445435
28,Guatemala,0.872001945972443,1.25558519363403,0.540239989757538,0.531310617923737,0.283488392829895,0.0772232785820961,2.89389109611511
29,Panama,1.23374843597412,1.37319254875183,0.706156134605408,0.550026834011078,0.21055693924427,0.070983923971653,2.30719995498657
30,France,1.43092346191406,1.38777685165405,0.844465851783752,0.470222115516663,0.129762306809425,0.172502428293228,2.00595474243164
31,Thailand,1.12786877155304,1.42579245567322,0.647239029407501,0.580200731754303,0.572123110294342,0.0316127352416515,2.03950834274292
32,Taiwan Province of China,1.43362653255463,1.38456535339355,0.793984234333038,0.361466586589813,0.258360475301743,0.0638292357325554,2.1266074180603
33,Spain,1.38439786434174,1.53209090232849,0.888960599899292,0.408781230449677,0.190133571624756,0.0709140971302986,1.92775774002075
34,Qatar,1.87076568603516,1.27429687976837,0.710098087787628,0.604130983352661,0.330473870038986,0.439299255609512,1.1454644203186
35,Colombia,1.07062232494354,1.4021829366684,0.595027923583984,0.477487415075302,0.149014472961426,0.0466687418520451,2.61606812477112
36,Saudi Arabia,1.53062355518341,1.28667759895325,0.590148329734802,0.449750572443008,0.147616013884544,0.27343225479126,2.0654296875
37,Trinidad and Tobago,1.36135590076447,1.3802285194397,0.519983291625977,0.518630743026733,0.325296461582184,0.0089648161083459,2.05324745178223
38,Kuwait,1.63295245170593,1.25969874858856,0.632105708122253,0.496337592601776,0.228289797902107,0.215159550309181,1.64042520523071
39,Slovakia,1.32539355754852,1.50505924224854,0.712732911109924,0.295817464590073,0.136544480919838,0.0242108516395092,2.09777665138245
40,Bahrain,1.48841226100922,1.32311046123505,0.653133034706116,0.536746919155121,0.172668486833572,0.257042169570923,1.65614938735962
41,Malaysia,1.29121541976929,1.28464603424072,0.618784427642822,0.402264982461929,0.416608929634094,0.0656007081270218,2.00444889068604
42,Nicaragua,0.737299203872681,1.28721570968628,0.653095960617065,0.447551846504211,0.301674216985703,0.130687981843948,2.51393055915833
43,Ecuador,1.00082039833069,1.28616881370544,0.685636222362518,0.4551981985569,0.150112465023994,0.140134647488594,2.29035258293152
44,El Salvador,0.909784495830536,1.18212509155273,0.596018552780151,0.432452529668808,0.0782579854130745,0.0899809598922729,2.7145938873291
45,Poland,1.29178786277771,1.44571197032928,0.699475347995758,0.520342111587524,0.158465966582298,0.0593078061938286,1.79772281646729
46,Uzbekistan,0.786441087722778,1.54896914958954,0.498272627592087,0.658248662948608,0.415983647108078,0.246528223156929,1.81691360473633
47,Italy,1.39506661891937,1.44492328166962,0.853144347667694,0.256450712680817,0.17278964817524,0.0280280914157629,1.81331205368042
48,Russia,1.28177809715271,1.46928238868713,0.547349333763123,0.373783111572266,0.0522638224065304,0.0329628810286522,2.20560741424561
49,Belize,0.907975316047668,1.08141779899597,0.450191766023636,0.547509372234344,0.240015640854836,0.0965810716152191,2.63195562362671
50,Japan,1.41691517829895,1.43633782863617,0.913475871086121,0.505625545978546,0.12057276815176,0.163760736584663,1.36322355270386
51,Lithuania,1.31458234786987,1.47351610660553,0.62894994020462,0.234231784939766,0.010164656676352,0.0118656428530812,2.22844052314758
52,Algeria,1.09186446666718,1.1462174654007,0.617584645748138,0.233335807919502,0.0694366469979286,0.146096110343933,2.56760382652283
53,Latvia,1.26074862480164,1.40471494197845,0.638566970825195,0.325707912445068,0.153074786067009,0.0738427266478539,1.99365520477295
54,South Korea,1.40167844295502,1.12827444076538,0.900214076042175,0.257921665906906,0.206674367189407,0.0632826685905457,1.88037800788879
55,Moldova,0.728870630264282,1.25182557106018,0.589465200901031,0.240729048848152,0.208779126405716,0.0100912861526012,2.80780839920044
56,Romania,1.21768391132355,1.15009129047394,0.685158312320709,0.457003742456436,0.133519917726517,0.00438790069893,2.17683148384094
57,Bolivia,0.833756566047668,1.22761905193329,0.473630249500275,0.558732926845551,0.22556072473526,0.0604777261614799,2.44327902793884
58,Turkmenistan,1.13077676296234,1.49314916133881,0.437726080417633,0.41827192902565,0.24992498755455,0.259270340204239,1.83290982246399
59,Kazakhstan,1.28455626964569,1.38436901569366,0.606041550636292,0.437454283237457,0.201964423060417,0.119282886385918,1.78489255905151
60,North Cyprus,1.3469113111496,1.18630337715149,0.834647238254547,0.471203625202179,0.266845703125,0.155353352427483,1.54915761947632
61,Slovenia,1.3412059545517,1.45251882076263,0.790828227996826,0.572575807571411,0.242649093270302,0.0451289787888527,1.31331729888916
62,Peru,1.03522527217865,1.21877038478851,0.630166113376617,0.450002878904343,0.126819714903831,0.0470490865409374,2.20726943016052
63,Mauritius,1.18939554691315,1.20956099033356,0.638007462024689,0.491247326135635,0.360933750867844,0.0421815551817417,1.6975839138031
64,Cyprus,1.35593807697296,1.13136327266693,0.84471470117569,0.355111539363861,0.271254301071167,0.0412379764020443,1.62124919891357
65,Estonia,1.32087934017181,1.47667109966278,0.695168316364288,0.479131430387497,0.0988908112049103,0.183248922228813,1.35750865936279
66,Belarus,1.15655755996704,1.44494521617889,0.637714266777039,0.295400261878967,0.15513750910759,0.156313821673393,1.72323298454285
67,Libya,1.10180306434631,1.35756433010101,0.520169019699097,0.465733230113983,0.152073666453362,0.0926102101802826,1.83501124382019
68,Turkey,1.19827437400818,1.33775317668915,0.637605607509613,0.300740599632263,0.0466930419206619,0.0996715798974037,1.87927794456482
69,Paraguay,0.932537317276001,1.50728487968445,0.579250693321228,0.473507791757584,0.224150657653809,0.091065913438797,1.6853334903717
70,"Hong Kong S.A.R., China",1.55167484283447,1.26279091835022,0.943062424659729,0.490968644618988,0.374465793371201,0.293933749198914,0.554633140563965
71,Philippines,0.85769921541214,1.25391757488251,0.468009054660797,0.585214674472809,0.193513423204422,0.0993318930268288,1.97260475158691
72,Serbia,1.06931757926941,1.25818979740143,0.65078467130661,0.208715528249741,0.220125883817673,0.0409037806093693,1.94708442687988
73,Jordan,0.991012394428253,1.23908889293671,0.604590058326721,0.418421149253845,0.172170460224152,0.11980327218771,1.79117655754089
74,Hungary,1.2860119342804,1.34313309192657,0.687763452529907,0.175863519310951,0.0784016624093056,0.0366369374096394,1.71645927429199
75,Jamaica,0.925579309463501,1.36821806430817,0.641022384166718,0.474307239055634,0.233818337321281,0.0552677810192108,1.61232566833496
76,Croatia,1.22255623340607,0.96798300743103,0.701288521289825,0.255772292613983,0.248002976179123,0.0431031100451946,1.85449242591858
77,Kosovo,0.951484382152557,1.13785350322723,0.541452050209045,0.260287940502167,0.319931447505951,0.0574716180562973,2.01054072380066
78,China,1.08116579055786,1.16083741188049,0.741415500640869,0.472787708044052,0.0288068410009146,0.0227942746132612,1.76493859291077
79,Pakistan,0.72688353061676,0.672690689563751,0.402047783136368,0.23521526157856,0.315446019172668,0.124348066747189,2.79248929023743
80,Indonesia,0.995538592338562,1.27444469928741,0.492345720529556,0.443323463201523,0.611704587936401,0.0153171354904771,1.42947697639465
81,Venezuela,1.12843120098114,1.43133759498596,0.617144227027893,0.153997123241425,0.0650196298956871,0.0644911229610443,1.78946375846863
82,Montenegro,1.12112903594971,1.23837649822235,0.667464673519135,0.194989055395126,0.197911024093628,0.0881741940975189,1.72919154167175
83,Morocco,0.878114581108093,0.774864435195923,0.59771066904068,0.408158332109451,0.0322099551558495,0.0877631828188896,2.45618939399719
84,Azerbaijan,1.15360176563263,1.15240025520325,0.540775775909424,0.398155838251114,0.0452693402767181,0.180987507104874,1.76248168945312
85,Dominican Republic,1.07937383651733,1.40241670608521,0.574873745441437,0.55258983373642,0.186967849731445,0.113945253193378,1.31946516036987
86,Greece,1.28948748111725,1.23941457271576,0.810198903083801,0.0957312509417534,0.0,0.04328977689147,1.74922156333923
87,Lebanon,1.07498753070831,1.12962424755096,0.735081076622009,0.288515985012054,0.264450758695602,0.037513829767704,1.69507384300232
88,Portugal,1.3151752948761,1.36704301834106,0.795843541622162,0.498465299606323,0.0951027125120163,0.0158694516867399,1.10768270492554
89,Bosnia and Herzegovina,0.982409417629242,1.0693359375,0.705186307430267,0.204403176903725,0.328867495059967,0.0,1.89217257499695
90,Honduras,0.730573117733002,1.14394497871399,0.582569479942322,0.348079860210419,0.236188873648643,0.0733454525470734,2.06581115722656
91,Macedonia,1.06457793712616,1.20789301395416,0.644948184490204,0.325905978679657,0.25376096367836,0.0602777935564518,1.6174693107605
92,Somalia,0.0226431842893362,0.721151351928711,0.113989137113094,0.602126955986023,0.291631311178207,0.282410323619843,3.11748456954956
93,Vietnam,0.788547575473785,1.27749133110046,0.652168989181519,0.571055591106415,0.234968051314354,0.0876332372426987,1.46231865882874
94,Nigeria,0.783756256103516,1.21577048301697,0.0569157302379608,0.394952565431595,0.230947196483612,0.0261215660721064,2.36539053916931
95,Tajikistan,0.524713635444641,1.27146327495575,0.529235124588013,0.471566706895828,0.248997643589973,0.146377146244049,1.84904932975769
96,Bhutan,0.885416388511658,1.34012651443481,0.495879292488098,0.501537680625916,0.474054545164108,0.173380389809608,1.14018440246582
97,Kyrgyzstan,0.596220076084137,1.39423859119415,0.553457796573639,0.454943388700485,0.42858037352562,0.0394391790032387,1.53672313690186
98,Nepal,0.479820191860199,1.17928326129913,0.504130780696869,0.440305948257446,0.394096165895462,0.0729755461215973,1.8912410736084
99,Mongolia,1.02723586559296,1.4930112361908,0.557783484458923,0.394143968820572,0.338464230298996,0.0329022891819477,1.11129236221313
100,South Africa,1.05469870567322,1.38478863239288,0.187080070376396,0.479246735572815,0.139362379908562,0.0725094974040985,1.51090860366821
101,Tunisia,1.00726580619812,0.868351459503174,0.613212049007416,0.289680689573288,0.0496933571994305,0.0867231488227844,1.89025115966797
102,Palestinian Territories,0.716249227523804,1.15564715862274,0.565666973590851,0.25471106171608,0.114173173904419,0.0892826020717621,1.8788902759552
103,Egypt,0.989701807498932,0.997471392154694,0.520187258720398,0.282110154628754,0.128631442785263,0.114381365478039,1.70216107368469
104,Bulgaria,1.1614590883255,1.43437945842743,0.708217680454254,0.289231717586517,0.113177694380283,0.0110515309497714,0.996139287948608
105,Sierra Leone,0.36842092871666,0.984136044979095,0.0055647538974881,0.318697690963745,0.293040901422501,0.0710951760411263,2.66845989227295
106,Cameroon,0.564305365085602,0.946018218994141,0.132892116904259,0.430388748645782,0.236298456788063,0.0513066314160824,2.3336455821991
107,Iran,1.15687310695648,0.711551249027252,0.639333188533783,0.249322608113289,0.387242913246155,0.048761073499918,1.49873495101929
108,Albania,0.996192753314972,0.803685247898102,0.731159746646881,0.381498634815216,0.201312944293022,0.0398642159998417,1.49044156074524
109,Bangladesh,0.586682975292206,0.735131740570068,0.533241033554077,0.478356659412384,0.172255352139473,0.123717859387398,1.97873616218567
110,Namibia,0.964434325695038,1.0984708070755,0.33861181139946,0.520303547382355,0.0771337449550629,0.0931469723582268,1.4818902015686
111,Kenya,0.560479462146759,1.06795072555542,0.309988349676132,0.452763766050339,0.444860309362411,0.0646413192152977,1.6519021987915
112,Mozambique,0.234305649995804,0.870701014995575,0.106654435396194,0.480791091918945,0.322228103876114,0.179436385631561,2.35565090179443
113,Myanmar,0.367110550403595,1.12323594093323,0.397522568702698,0.514492034912109,0.838075160980225,0.188816204667091,1.11529040336609
114,Senegal,0.479309022426605,1.17969191074371,0.409362852573395,0.377922266721725,0.183468893170357,0.115460447967052,1.78964614868164
115,Zambia,0.636406779289246,1.00318729877472,0.257835894823074,0.461603492498398,0.249580144882202,0.0782135501503944,1.82670545578003
116,Iraq,1.10271048545837,0.978613197803497,0.501180469989777,0.288555532693863,0.19963726401329,0.107215754687786,1.31890726089478
117,Gabon,1.1982102394104,1.1556202173233,0.356578588485718,0.312328577041626,0.0437853783369064,0.0760467872023582,1.32291626930237
118,Ethiopia,0.339233845472336,0.86466920375824,0.353409707546234,0.408842742443085,0.312650740146637,0.165455713868141,2.01574373245239
119,Sri Lanka,1.00985014438629,1.25997638702393,0.625130832195282,0.561213254928589,0.490863561630249,0.0736539661884308,0.419389247894287
120,Armenia,0.900596737861633,1.00748372077942,0.637524425983429,0.198303267359734,0.0834880918264389,0.0266744215041399,1.5214991569519
121,India,0.792221248149872,0.754372596740723,0.455427616834641,0.469987004995346,0.231538489460945,0.0922268852591515,1.5191171169281
122,Mauritania,0.648457288742065,1.2720308303833,0.285349279642105,0.0960980430245399,0.201870024204254,0.136957004666328,1.65163731575012
123,Congo (Brazzaville),0.808964252471924,0.832044363021851,0.28995743393898,0.435025870800018,0.120852127671242,0.0796181336045265,1.72413563728333
124,Georgia,0.950612664222717,0.57061493396759,0.649546980857849,0.309410035610199,0.0540088154375553,0.251666635274887,1.50013780593872
125,Congo (Kinshasa),0.0921023488044739,1.22902345657349,0.191407024860382,0.235961347818375,0.246455833315849,0.0602413564920425,2.22495865821838
126,Mali,0.476180493831635,1.28147339820862,0.169365674257278,0.306613743305206,0.183354198932648,0.104970246553421,1.66819095611572
127,Ivory Coast,0.603048920631409,0.904780030250549,0.0486421696841717,0.447706192731857,0.201237469911575,0.130061775445938,1.84496426582336
128,Cambodia,0.601765096187592,1.00623834133148,0.429783403873444,0.633375823497772,0.385922968387604,0.0681059509515762,1.04294109344482
129,Sudan,0.65951669216156,1.21400856971741,0.290920823812485,0.0149958552792668,0.182317450642586,0.089847519993782,1.68706583976746
130,Ghana,0.667224824428558,0.873664736747742,0.295637726783752,0.423026293516159,0.256923943758011,0.0253363698720932,1.57786750793457
131,Ukraine,0.89465194940567,1.39453756809235,0.575903952121735,0.122974775731564,0.270061463117599,0.0230294708162546,0.814382314682007
132,Uganda,0.381430715322495,1.12982773780823,0.217632606625557,0.443185955286026,0.325766056776047,0.057069718837738,1.526362657547
133,Burkina Faso,0.3502277135849,1.04328000545502,0.215844258666039,0.324367851018906,0.250864684581757,0.120328105986118,1.72721290588379
134,Niger,0.161925330758095,0.993025004863739,0.26850500702858,0.36365869641304,0.228673845529556,0.138572946190834,1.87398338317871
135,Malawi,0.233442038297653,0.512568831443787,0.315089583396912,0.466914653778076,0.287170469760895,0.0727116540074348,2.08178615570068
136,Chad,0.438012987375259,0.953855872154236,0.0411347150802612,0.16234202682972,0.216113850474358,0.0535818822681904,2.07123804092407
137,Zimbabwe,0.375846534967422,1.08309590816498,0.196763753890991,0.336384207010269,0.189143493771553,0.0953753814101219,1.59797024726868
138,Lesotho,0.521021246910095,1.19009518623352,0.0,0.390661299228668,0.157497271895409,0.119094640016556,1.42983531951904
139,Angola,0.858428180217743,1.10441195964813,0.0498686656355858,0.0,0.097926490008831,0.0697203353047371,1.61448240280151
140,Afghanistan,0.401477217674255,0.581543326377869,0.180746778845787,0.106179520487785,0.311870932579041,0.0611578300595284,2.15080118179321
141,Botswana,1.12209415435791,1.22155499458313,0.341755509376526,0.505196332931519,0.0993484482169151,0.0985831990838051,0.3779137134552
142,Benin,0.431085407733917,0.435299843549728,0.209930211305618,0.425962775945663,0.207948461174965,0.0609290152788162,1.88563096523285
143,Madagascar,0.305808693170547,0.913020372390747,0.375223308801651,0.189196765422821,0.208732530474663,0.0672319754958153,1.58461260795593
144,Haiti,0.368610262870789,0.640449821949005,0.277321130037308,0.0303698573261499,0.489203780889511,0.0998721495270729,1.69716763496399
145,Yemen,0.591683447360992,0.93538224697113,0.310080915689468,0.249463722109795,0.104125209152699,0.0567674227058887,1.34560060501099
146,South Sudan,0.39724862575531,0.601323127746582,0.163486003875732,0.147062435746193,0.285670816898346,0.116793513298035,1.87956738471985
147,Liberia,0.119041793048382,0.872117936611176,0.229918196797371,0.332881182432175,0.26654988527298,0.0389482490718365,1.67328596115112
148,Guinea,0.244549930095673,0.791244685649872,0.194129139184952,0.348587512969971,0.264815092086792,0.110937617719173,1.55231189727783
149,Togo,0.305444717407227,0.431882530450821,0.247105568647385,0.38042613863945,0.196896150708199,0.0956650152802467,1.83722925186157
150,Rwanda,0.368745893239975,0.945707023143768,0.326424807310104,0.581843852996826,0.252756029367447,0.455220013856888,0.540061235427856
151,Syria,0.777153134346008,0.396102607250214,0.50053334236145,0.0815394446253777,0.493663728237152,0.151347130537033,1.06157350540161
152,Tanzania,0.511135876178741,1.04198980331421,0.364509284496307,0.390017777681351,0.354256361722946,0.0660351067781448,0.621130466461182
153,Burundi,0.091622568666935,0.629793584346771,0.151610791683197,0.0599007532000542,0.204435184597969,0.0841479450464249,1.68302416801453
154,Central African Republic,0.0,0.0,0.0187726859003305,0.270842045545578,0.280876487493515,0.0565650761127472,2.06600475311279
```

Comment: Can you show us the data? To reproduce your error. Any link **or** maybe add top 10 rows of your data here (separated by comma, csv).

Comment: Don't include your data as a screenshot. Put it as **text**.

Comment: Sorry for that. I changed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took 10 countries as sample input:

```
       Country  Economy  GDP per Capita     Family  Health  Life Expectancy   \
0       Norway                  1.616463  1.533524                  0.796667   
1      Denmark                  1.482383  1.551122                  0.792566   
2      Iceland                  1.480633  1.610574                  0.833552   
3  Switzerland                  1.564980  1.516912                  0.858131   
4      Finland                  1.443572  1.540247                  0.809158   

    Freedom  Generosity  Trust  Government Corruption   Dystopia Residual  
0  0.635423    0.362012                       0.315964           2.277027  
1  0.626007    0.355280                       0.400770           2.313707  
2  0.627163    0.475540                       0.153527           2.322715  
3  0.620071    0.290549                       0.367007           2.276716  
4  0.617951    0.245483                       0.382612           2.430182
```

Code:

```
df.index = df.Country
df.plot.barh(stacked=True, figsize=(10, 5))
plt.legend(title='Parameters', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Plot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. But I need the horizontal stacked bar, because 155 countries won't fit side by side. That's why I cant use the df.plot function unfortunately

Comment: Okay got it.. I edited the answer to make the bars horizontal.. Hope that is what you require?

Comment: OHHHH Godddd I didn't even know that stacked wirked in barh too, so very stupid of me LOL. Thank you so much

Comment: Cool.. pls dont forget to accept and vote up if you like the solution

Comment: Hey, any idea on how to sort this from max to min? Sorting the dataframe doesn't seem to work